# Row push to next view react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying run navigation from Row. i Want push next view when i click row. I am using StackNavigator from react-navigation. Row is other file than List.

Code with ListView:

```js
const MyScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
  <View style={styles.view}>
  <ListView
    style={styles.container}
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={Row}
  />
</View>
);
```

My Row:

```js
const Row = (props) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Details', {name: 'Lucy'})}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
renderRow={() => Row({navigation})}
```

You have to pass `props` into `Row` this way, to make `navigation.navigate` happens.